# Nested Sql select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the following sql query ?

```
Select *, 
(SELECT [DiseaseID], COUNT(*) AS [Rank] FROM [DiseaseSymptom] WHERE
    ([SymptomID] IN(1, 5)) GROUP BY [DiseaseID] ORDER BY [Rank] DESC)
FROM Disease WHERE GenderID in (1, 3)
```

I have 2 tables one contains disease and the gender it is associated with

**Disease**

```
+-----------+-------------------+----------+
| DiseaseID |    DiseaseName    | GenderID |
+-----------+-------------------+----------+
|         1 | Fever             |        3 |
|         2 | Flu               |        3 |
|         3 | Lady Disease      |        2 |
|         4 | Gentlemen Disease |        1 |
+-----------+-------------------+----------+
```

Gender 1 = Male, 2 = Female, 3 = Common

And a Symptom Disease Matrix like this

**DiseaseSymptom**

```
+-----------+-----------+----------+
| DiseaseID | SymptomID | DissymID |
+-----------+-----------+----------+
|         1 |         1 |        1 |
|         1 |         2 |        3 |
|         1 |         4 |        4 |
|         2 |         1 |        5 |
|         2 |         3 |        9 |
|         2 |         4 |        6 |
|         2 |         5 |        7 |
+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

I get symptoms from user and match it in the `DiseaseSymptom` table and rank it according to the number of symptoms matched (inner sql statement)

In the outer statement I simply want get the result from inner statement and evaluate whether it belongs to specific gender. The error I get when I try to run the above query is

```
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: what is the error you got ?

Comment: Now that I understand what the query is trying to do, I'm not 100% sure that it does what you intend.  You should provide sample data, desired results, and (in general) say what is going wrong if there is a problem.

Comment: Sorry. I have Updated the question with what I am trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

You are using a subquery with `group by`.  Your intention is to have a correlated subquery.  The problem is that the subquery is returning more than one row.  I think this is what you want:

```
Select d.*, 
      (SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Rank]
       FROM [DiseaseSymptom] ds
       WHERE [SymptomID] IN (1, 5)) AND ds.DiseaseId = d.DiseaseId
      )
FROM Disease d
WHERE GenderID in (1, 3);
```

Comment: ...Given the outer `SELECT` is getting more columns from a master table, I seriously doubt just doing this will be sufficient.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse . . . I completely misread the question.  Thank you.

Comment: I tried your query and I get the "Column 'DiseaseSymptom.DiseaseID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause" error again.

Comment: @n00b_c0der . . . The nested select should only return one column, not two, and I'm guessing you want the `count(*)`.

Answer (score 0):

Subqueries in select clause must only generate a scalar value, not a resultset with multiple columns or rows. if you want both then put the subquery in the from clause (properly correlated), and refer to the two different vqlues in the select clause

```
 Select d.*, z.DeseaseId, z.Rank
 FROM Disease d
     join (SELECT DiseaseID, COUNT(*) Rank
           FROM DiseaseSymptom
           WHERE SymptomID IN(1, 5) 
           GROUP BY DiseaseID) Z
       On z.DeseaseId = d.DeseaseId
 WHERE GenderID in (1, 3)
 Order By z.Rank
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Common Table Expression (cte) like this:

```
    with cte as (SELECT [DiseaseID], GenderID, COUNT(*) AS [Rank] FROM [DiseaseSymptom] WHERE
    ([SymptomID] IN(1, 5)) GROUP BY [DiseaseID],GenderID ORDER BY [Rank] DESC)
    select * FROM cte WHERE GenderID in (1, 3)
```

Hope this help ;)

Comment: It's not clear what the OP is really trying for, what problem is it you think this will solve?  You're also completely ignoring one of the tables in the original post, so it's unlikely you're returning all the data the OP needs.

Answer (score 0):

There is really no need to have a nested query, just join and filter

```
SELECT d.DiseaseID, d.DiseaseName, d.GenderID
     , Symptoms = Count(ds.SymptomID)
FROM   Disease d
       INNER JOIN DiseaseSymptom ds ON d.DiseaseID = ds.DiseaseID
WHERE  ds.SymptomID IN (1, 5)
  AND  d.GenderID IN (1, 3)
GROUP BY d.DiseaseID, d.DiseaseName, d.GenderID
ORDER BY Count(SymptomID) Desc
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c03ae/3) Demo